# ヘルプセンターの "どうしたら再オープンできますか？" に余計な文字が混入している

Tags: バグ, 完了, ヘルプ

非常に些細な内容なのですが、ヘルプセンターの [質問のクローズに反対する場合はどうしたらいいですか？どうしたら再オープンできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) の説明中に、余計な文字が混入しています。

ただの縦棒にも見えますが、検索してみると一応はアルファベットの "L" らしいです。
(環境によっては L を上下逆さにしてくっつけたような見たこと無い文字で表示されます)

**該当箇所:** ("さらに次のことができます" の段落)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

余計な文字を削除いたしました。[反映](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)も確認されました。

[image: アルファベットの "L" さん、さよなら]